# Is it bad practice to create Divs just to have multiple controllers?

Tags: html, angularjs, angularjs-scope, asp.net-web-api2, scoping

**Is a bad practice to be creating divs in your HTML just to be able to have multiple controllers?**

Since you cannot have them in one also the approach of having multiple directives with separate controllers seems like a hack, but correct me if I am wrong.

So I have 2 controllers - one is called **ConvertController** and the other one is called **YouTubeLinkUIController**.

The responsibility of the first one is to hit my Web API controller and convert the given YouTube link into an audio.

The responsibility of the second one is to control some of the UI functionality.

In order to follow the single responsibility principle, I have separated them into 2 different controllers and therein lies the problem.

My last commit, specifically Index.cshtml shows the full code, but for the sake of not making this messy I will abreviate it for this post.

https://github.com/AvetisG/TubeToTune/commit/e68ba42f20498c9a4e032328aed6d68c27b9b2cb

```
<div class="container" ng-app="TubeToTuneApp" ng-controller="YouTubeLinkUIController">

    ... more code

    @*Scoping the Convert Controller*@
    <div ng-controller="ConvertController">

        ... more code

    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looking at your github commit message it looks like you split the controllers because you didn't want to have too much code in your ui controller.

This is a perfect example of when an angular service is in order. You can think of a service like a controller without all the overhead and that can be easily called from another controller

[Angular Service Documentation](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/services)

What you should do is define a service that calls your api and then

```js
angular.module('youTube', [])

.controller('YouTubeLinkController', ['$scope', 'convert',
  function($scope, convert) {
    $scope.convertLink = function() {
      $scope.convertMessage = convert.convertYoutube()
    };
  }
])

.factory('convert', [
  function() {
    var convertService = {};

    convertService.convertYoutube = function(data) {
      //Make api call
      return "Conversion Done";
    }

    return convertService;
  }
]);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>

<body ng-app="youTube">
  <div ng-controller="YouTubeLinkController">
    {{convertMessage}}
    <button ng-click="convertLink()">Convert</button>
  </div>
</body>
```

Naturally you should define the service in it's own page. That way controllers are only used for interacting with UI. It also solves your  problem

Answer (score 1):

It's absolutely fine to use divs\spans and nested structures and use `ng-controller` with it.

When you add `ng-controller` to a html element in a way you are creating a component with a model-view and controller.

A complex component can have nested sub components that perform very specific functionality and in a way you are demarcating such parts with `ng-controller` . To take it a step further if you convert these component into directives, with their own controller + template(view) and that accept model from a data source, then you have a reusable component that you can use throughout the app.

Answer (score 0):

To me, it looks more like your ConvertController should be written as a service, rather than as a controller. This would still follow single responsibility, but would probably align closer to your intended functionality: UI functionality and view data in the controller, business logic in the service.

That said, having two controllers on a single view might not be bad practice, this leads to confusing mark-up in cases like the following:

```
<button type="submit" class="btn btn-xlarge btn-warning btn-block" ng-if="AreThereYouTubeLinks() == true" ng-click="ConvertToTunes(YouTubeLinks)">
```

You may know personally which controllers `AreThereYouTubeLinks()`, `ConvertToTunes()`, and `YouTubeLinks` belong to, but this will be confusing in the long-term (and can lead to issues with scope-bound variables like `YouTubeLinks`.

Luckily, there's a syntax for helping clear this up- Controller As - and [Todd Motto wrote an excellent article](http://toddmotto.com/digging-into-angulars-controller-as-syntax/) explaining how to use it and what problems it helps solve. In brief, it would turn something like this:

```
<div ng-controller="MainCtrl">
  {{ title }}
  <div ng-controller="AnotherCtrl">
    {{ title }}
    <div ng-controller="YetAnotherCtrl">
      {{ title }}
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

in to this:

```
<div ng-controller="MainCtrl as main">
  {{ main.title }}
  <div ng-controller="AnotherCtrl as another">
    {{ another.title }}
    <div ng-controller="YetAnotherCtrl as yet">
      {{ yet.title }}
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

In your case, you would end up with this safer, more understandable mark-up:

```
<div class="container" ng-app="TubeToTuneApp" ng-controller="YouTubeLinkUIController as linkCtrl">

    ... more code

    @*Scoping the Convert Controller*@
    <div ng-controller="ConvertController as converter">

        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-xlarge btn-warning btn-block" ng-if="linkCtrl.AreThereYouTubeLinks() == true" ng-click="converter.ConvertToTunes(linkCtrl.YouTubeLinks)">

    </div>
</div>
```

If you're going to stick with two controllers, you probably want to consider investing the time to getting comfortable with Controller As.